# Docker: while create dockerfile npm package module error

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

When m trying to craete image with docker file its saying...

> The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -s' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

COPY package-lock.json /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install -s
```

Comment: There should be an explanation before your error line.

Comment: Can you share the full output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually every OS has their own commands, i was using apt-get in alpine, that was wrong.

And alpine comes with short and light versions where we can use dependencies according to our requirement.

And in alpine "apk add" has used instead of "apt-get"
here is my changed docker file.

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

COPY package-lock.json /app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
apk add --no-cache bash git openssh && \
apk add --update alpine-sdk

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del .gyp

RUN npm install

COPY . /app